# SQLite how to query this?

Tags: sql, sqlite

Tables:

```
CREATE TABLE "Employees" (
    "Id"    INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
    "Name"  TEXT NOT NULL,
    "EnrollmentDate"    INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "BaseSalary"    REAL NOT NULL,
    "ChiefId"   INTEGER,
    "PositionId"    INTEGER
)

CREATE TABLE "Position" (
    "Id"    INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
    "PositionName"  INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "YearPercent"   INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "MaxYearPercent"    INTEGER
)
```

Data Positions:

```
INSERT INTO "main"."Position" ("Id", "PositionName", "YearPercent", "MaxYearPercent") VALUES ('1', 'Employee', '0.03', '0.3');
INSERT INTO "main"."Position" ("Id", "PositionName", "YearPercent", "MaxYearPercent") VALUES ('2', 'Manager', '0.05', '0.4');
INSERT INTO "main"."Position" ("Id", "PositionName", "YearPercent", "MaxYearPercent") VALUES ('3', 'Salesman', '0.01', '0.35');
```

Data Employees:

```
INSERT INTO "main"."Employees" ("Id", "Name", "EnrollmentDate", "BaseSalary", "ChiefId", "PositionId") VALUES ('1', 'A', '2019-05-18', '10000.0', '5', '1');
INSERT INTO "main"."Employees" ("Id", "Name", "EnrollmentDate", "BaseSalary", "ChiefId", "PositionId") VALUES ('2', 'B', '2019-07-26', '10000.0', '5', '1');
INSERT INTO "main"."Employees" ("Id", "Name", "EnrollmentDate", "BaseSalary", "ChiefId", "PositionId") VALUES ('3', 'C', '1990-09-19', '15000.0', '12', '1');
INSERT INTO "main"."Employees" ("Id", "Name", "EnrollmentDate", "BaseSalary", "ChiefId", "PositionId") VALUES ('4', 'D', '2017-01-20', '12000.0', '6', '1');
INSERT INTO "main"."Employees" ("Id", "Name", "EnrollmentDate", "BaseSalary", "ChiefId", "PositionId") VALUES ('5', 'E', '2017-01-20', '12000.0', '', '2');
INSERT INTO "main"."Employees" ("Id", "Name", "EnrollmentDate", "BaseSalary", "ChiefId", "PositionId") VALUES ('6', 'F', '2016-01-20', '18000.0', '7', '2');
INSERT INTO "main"."Employees" ("Id", "Name", "EnrollmentDate", "BaseSalary", "ChiefId", "PositionId") VALUES ('7', 'G', '2015-05-15', '11500', '', '2');
INSERT INTO "main"."Employees" ("Id", "Name", "EnrollmentDate", "BaseSalary", "ChiefId", "PositionId") VALUES ('8', 'H', '2009-03-01', '12300', '7', '2');
INSERT INTO "main"."Employees" ("Id", "Name", "EnrollmentDate", "BaseSalary", "ChiefId", "PositionId") VALUES ('9', 'I', '2001-02-12', '14000', '', '3');
INSERT INTO "main"."Employees" ("Id", "Name", "EnrollmentDate", "BaseSalary", "ChiefId", "PositionId") VALUES ('10', 'G', '2013-05-20', '25000', '8', '3');
INSERT INTO "main"."Employees" ("Id", "Name", "EnrollmentDate", "BaseSalary", "ChiefId", "PositionId") VALUES ('11', 'K', '2019-07-26', '5000', '', '3');
INSERT INTO "main"."Employees" ("Id", "Name", "EnrollmentDate", "BaseSalary", "ChiefId", "PositionId") VALUES ('12', 'L', '2016-01-20', '2000', '', '3');
```

The whole question sounds: "There are 3 groups of employees - **Employee**, **Manager** and **Salesman**. Each employee may be the boss. Every employee except **Employee** may have subordinates.

The employee salary is calculated as follows:

- **Employee** - BaseSalary + 3% for each year of work, but not more than 30%
- **Manager** - BaseSalary + 5% for each year, but not more than 40% + 0.5% of subordinates salaries on the 1st level of hierarchy
- **Salesman** - BaseSalary + 1% for each year, but not more than 35% + 0.3% of subordinates salaries the whole hierarchy

The query: "Select all employees with their salaries for last half year (months should be horizontal)".

I tried to achive this with small steps. First of all, I counted salaries without subordinates (in weird way i think):

```
SELECT Name,
    CASE 
        WHEN (SELECT CAST((strftime('%Y', date('now', '-1 month')) + strftime('%j', date('now', '-1 month')) / 365.2422) - (strftime('%Y', EnrollmentDate) + strftime('%j', EnrollmentDate) / 365.2422) AS INT)) * (SELECT YearPercent FROM Position WHERE Position.Id = Employees.PositionId) >= (SELECT MaxYearPercent FROM Position WHERE Position.Id = Employees.PositionId) THEN BaseSalary + BaseSalary * (SELECT MaxYearPercent FROM Position WHERE Position.Id = Employees.PositionId)
        ELSE BaseSalary + BaseSalary * (SELECT CAST((strftime('%Y', date('now', '-1 month')) + strftime('%j', date('now', '-1 month')) / 365.2422) - (strftime('%Y', EnrollmentDate) + strftime('%j', EnrollmentDate) / 365.2422) AS INT)) * (SELECT YearPercent FROM Position WHERE Position.Id = Employees.PositionId)
    END AS '1 month',
    CASE 
        WHEN (SELECT CAST((strftime('%Y', date('now', '-2 month')) + strftime('%j', date('now', '-2 month')) / 365.2422) - (strftime('%Y', EnrollmentDate) + strftime('%j', EnrollmentDate) / 365.2422) AS INT)) * (SELECT YearPercent FROM Position WHERE Position.Id = Employees.PositionId) >= (SELECT MaxYearPercent FROM Position WHERE Position.Id = Employees.PositionId) THEN BaseSalary + BaseSalary * (SELECT MaxYearPercent FROM Position WHERE Position.Id = Employees.PositionId)
        ELSE BaseSalary + BaseSalary * (SELECT CAST((strftime('%Y', date('now', '-2 month')) + strftime('%j', date('now', '-2 month')) / 365.2422) - (strftime('%Y', EnrollmentDate) + strftime('%j', EnrollmentDate) / 365.2422) AS INT)) * (SELECT YearPercent FROM Position WHERE Position.Id = Employees.PositionId)
    END AS '2 month',
    CASE 
        WHEN (SELECT CAST((strftime('%Y', date('now', '-3 month')) + strftime('%j', date('now', '-3 month')) / 365.2422) - (strftime('%Y', EnrollmentDate) + strftime('%j', EnrollmentDate) / 365.2422) AS INT)) * (SELECT YearPercent FROM Position WHERE Position.Id = Employees.PositionId) >= (SELECT MaxYearPercent FROM Position WHERE Position.Id = Employees.PositionId) THEN BaseSalary + BaseSalary * (SELECT MaxYearPercent FROM Position WHERE Position.Id = Employees.PositionId)
        ELSE BaseSalary + BaseSalary * (SELECT CAST((strftime('%Y', date('now', '-3 month')) + strftime('%j', date('now', '-3 month')) / 365.2422) - (strftime('%Y', EnrollmentDate) + strftime('%j', EnrollmentDate) / 365.2422) AS INT)) * (SELECT YearPercent FROM Position WHERE Position.Id = Employees.PositionId)
    END AS '3 month',
    CASE 
        WHEN (SELECT CAST((strftime('%Y', date('now', '-4 month')) + strftime('%j', date('now', '-4 month')) / 365.2422) - (strftime('%Y', EnrollmentDate) + strftime('%j', EnrollmentDate) / 365.2422) AS INT)) * (SELECT YearPercent FROM Position WHERE Position.Id = Employees.PositionId) >= (SELECT MaxYearPercent FROM Position WHERE Position.Id = Employees.PositionId) THEN BaseSalary + BaseSalary * (SELECT MaxYearPercent FROM Position WHERE Position.Id = Employees.PositionId)
        ELSE BaseSalary + BaseSalary * (SELECT CAST((strftime('%Y', date('now', '-4 month')) + strftime('%j', date('now', '-4 month')) / 365.2422) - (strftime('%Y', EnrollmentDate) + strftime('%j', EnrollmentDate) / 365.2422) AS INT)) * (SELECT YearPercent FROM Position WHERE Position.Id = Employees.PositionId)
    END AS '4 month',
    CASE 
        WHEN (SELECT CAST((strftime('%Y', date('now', '-5 month')) + strftime('%j', date('now', '-5 month')) / 365.2422) - (strftime('%Y', EnrollmentDate) + strftime('%j', EnrollmentDate) / 365.2422) AS INT)) * (SELECT YearPercent FROM Position WHERE Position.Id = Employees.PositionId) >= (SELECT MaxYearPercent FROM Position WHERE Position.Id = Employees.PositionId) THEN BaseSalary + BaseSalary * (SELECT MaxYearPercent FROM Position WHERE Position.Id = Employees.PositionId)
        ELSE BaseSalary + BaseSalary * (SELECT CAST((strftime('%Y', date('now', '-5 month')) + strftime('%j', date('now', '-5 month')) / 365.2422) - (strftime('%Y', EnrollmentDate) + strftime('%j', EnrollmentDate) / 365.2422) AS INT)) * (SELECT YearPercent FROM Position WHERE Position.Id = Employees.PositionId)
    END AS '5 month',
    CASE 
        WHEN (SELECT CAST((strftime('%Y', date('now', '-6 month')) + strftime('%j', date('now', '-6 month')) / 365.2422) - (strftime('%Y', EnrollmentDate) + strftime('%j', EnrollmentDate) / 365.2422) AS INT)) * (SELECT YearPercent FROM Position WHERE Position.Id = Employees.PositionId) >= (SELECT MaxYearPercent FROM Position WHERE Position.Id = Employees.PositionId) THEN BaseSalary + BaseSalary * (SELECT MaxYearPercent FROM Position WHERE Position.Id = Employees.PositionId)
        ELSE BaseSalary + BaseSalary * (SELECT CAST((strftime('%Y', date('now', '-6 month')) + strftime('%j', date('now', '-6 month')) / 365.2422) - (strftime('%Y', EnrollmentDate) + strftime('%j', EnrollmentDate) / 365.2422) AS INT)) * (SELECT YearPercent FROM Position WHERE Position.Id = Employees.PositionId)
    END AS '6 month'
FROM Employees;
```

Then I counted salaries for Managers (1st level of hierarchy subordinates):

```
SELECT e.Name, SUM(s.BaseSalary)
FROM Employees e
JOIN Employees s on e.Id = s.ChiefId
GROUP BY e.Name;
```

The last step I made count salaries for Salesman (the whole hierarchy):

```
WITH Subordinates (Id, ParentId) AS (
    SELECT Id, Id as ParentId
    FROM Employees
    UNION ALL
    SELECT e.Id, s.ParentId
    FROM Employees e INNER JOIN Subordinates s ON (s.Id = e.ChiefId)
)
SELECT e.Name, sum(e1.BaseSalary)
FROM Subordinates s
JOIN Employees e on e.Id = s.ParentId
LEFT JOIN Employees e1 on e1.Id = s.Id and s.Id != s.ParentId
GROUP BY e.Name
ORDER BY e.Name;
```

Next step should be just bake that in 1 query i stuck on this (query just doesn't count the Employees salaries correct and i have no idea why is it):

```
WITH M1DIF AS (
    SELECT CAST((strftime('%Y', date('now', '-1 month')) + strftime('%j', date('now', '-1 month')) / 365.2422) - (strftime('%Y', EnrollmentDate) + strftime('%j', EnrollmentDate) / 365.2422) AS INT)
    FROM Employees
),
M2DIF AS (
    SELECT CAST((strftime('%Y', date('now', '-2 month')) + strftime('%j', date('now', '-2 month')) / 365.2422) - (strftime('%Y', EnrollmentDate) + strftime('%j', EnrollmentDate) / 365.2422) AS INT)
    FROM Employees
),
M3DIF AS (
    SELECT CAST((strftime('%Y', date('now', '-3 month')) + strftime('%j', date('now', '-3 month')) / 365.2422) - (strftime('%Y', EnrollmentDate) + strftime('%j', EnrollmentDate) / 365.2422) AS INT)
    FROM Employees
),
M4DIF AS (
    SELECT CAST((strftime('%Y', date('now', '-4 month')) + strftime('%j', date('now', '-4 month')) / 365.2422) - (strftime('%Y', EnrollmentDate) + strftime('%j', EnrollmentDate) / 365.2422) AS INT)
    FROM Employees
),
M5DIF AS (
    SELECT CAST((strftime('%Y', date('now', '-5 month')) + strftime('%j', date('now', '-5 month')) / 365.2422) - (strftime('%Y', EnrollmentDate) + strftime('%j', EnrollmentDate) / 365.2422) AS INT)
    FROM Employees
),
M6DIF AS (
    SELECT CAST((strftime('%Y', date('now', '-6 month')) + strftime('%j', date('now', '-6 month')) / 365.2422) - (strftime('%Y', EnrollmentDate) + strftime('%j', EnrollmentDate) / 365.2422) AS INT)
    FROM Employees
)

SELECT e.Name,
    CASE 
        WHEN (SELECT * FROM M1DIF) * (SELECT YearPercent FROM Position WHERE Position.Id = e.PositionId) >= (SELECT MaxYearPercent FROM Position WHERE Position.Id = e.PositionId)
        THEN 
            CASE
                WHEN e.PositionId = 1 THEN e.BaseSalary + e.BaseSalary * (SELECT MaxYearPercent FROM Position WHERE Position.Id = e.PositionId)
                WHEN e.PositionId = 2 THEN e.BaseSalary + e.BaseSalary * (SELECT MaxYearPercent FROM Position WHERE Position.Id = e.PositionId) + (CASE WHEN (SELECT SUM(e1.BaseSalary) FROM Employees e1 WHERE e1.ChiefId = e.Id) IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE (SELECT SUM(e1.BaseSalary) FROM Employees e1 WHERE e1.ChiefId = e.Id) END) * 0.05
            END
        ELSE 
            CASE
                WHEN e.PositionId = 1 THEN e.BaseSalary + e.BaseSalary * (SELECT * FROM M1DIF) * (SELECT YearPercent FROM Position WHERE Position.Id = e.PositionId)
                WHEN e.PositionId = 2 THEN e.BaseSalary + e.BaseSalary * (SELECT * FROM M1DIF) * (SELECT YearPercent FROM Position WHERE Position.Id = e.PositionId) + (CASE WHEN (SELECT SUM(e1.BaseSalary) FROM Employees e1 WHERE e1.ChiefId = e.Id) IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE (SELECT SUM(e1.BaseSalary) FROM Employees e1 WHERE e1.ChiefId = e.Id) END) * 0.05
            END
    END AS '1 month',
    CASE 
        WHEN (SELECT * FROM M2DIF) * (SELECT YearPercent FROM Position WHERE Position.Id = e.PositionId) >= (SELECT MaxYearPercent FROM Position WHERE Position.Id = e.PositionId)
        THEN e.BaseSalary + e.BaseSalary * (SELECT MaxYearPercent FROM Position WHERE Position.Id = e.PositionId)
        ELSE e.BaseSalary + e.BaseSalary * (SELECT * FROM M2DIF) * (SELECT YearPercent FROM Position WHERE Position.Id = e.PositionId)
    END AS '2 month',
    CASE 
        WHEN (SELECT * FROM M3DIF) * (SELECT YearPercent FROM Position WHERE Position.Id = e.PositionId) >= (SELECT MaxYearPercent FROM Position WHERE Position.Id = e.PositionId) 
        THEN e.BaseSalary + e.BaseSalary * (SELECT MaxYearPercent FROM Position WHERE Position.Id = e.PositionId)
        ELSE e.BaseSalary + e.BaseSalary * (SELECT * FROM M3DIF) * (SELECT YearPercent FROM Position WHERE Position.Id = e.PositionId)
    END AS '3 month',
    CASE 
        WHEN (SELECT * FROM M4DIF) * (SELECT YearPercent FROM Position WHERE Position.Id = e.PositionId) >= (SELECT MaxYearPercent FROM Position WHERE Position.Id = e.PositionId) 
        THEN e.BaseSalary + e.BaseSalary * (SELECT MaxYearPercent FROM Position WHERE Position.Id = e.PositionId)
        ELSE e.BaseSalary + e.BaseSalary * (SELECT * FROM M4DIF) * (SELECT YearPercent FROM Position WHERE Position.Id = e.PositionId)
    END AS '4 month',
    CASE 
        WHEN (SELECT * FROM M5DIF) * (SELECT YearPercent FROM Position WHERE Position.Id = e.PositionId) >= (SELECT MaxYearPercent FROM Position WHERE Position.Id = e.PositionId) 
        THEN e.BaseSalary + e.BaseSalary * (SELECT MaxYearPercent FROM Position WHERE Position.Id = e.PositionId)
        ELSE e.BaseSalary + e.BaseSalary * (SELECT * FROM M5DIF) * (SELECT YearPercent FROM Position WHERE Position.Id = e.PositionId)
    END AS '5 month',
    CASE 
        WHEN (SELECT * FROM M6DIF) * (SELECT YearPercent FROM Position WHERE Position.Id = e.PositionId) >= (SELECT MaxYearPercent FROM Position WHERE Position.Id = e.PositionId) 
        THEN e.BaseSalary + e.BaseSalary * (SELECT MaxYearPercent FROM Position WHERE Position.Id = e.PositionId)
        ELSE e.BaseSalary + e.BaseSalary * (SELECT * FROM M6DIF) * (SELECT YearPercent FROM Position WHERE Position.Id = e.PositionId)
    END AS '6 month'
FROM Employees e;
```

P.S. I'm very newbie to SQL.

Edit: Got the idea that it was wrong decision to use WITH statement.

Comment: Homework questions should include the question, the definition of all tables required to answer the question, data needed to populate those tables, and examples of what you've tried **in the question itself**. Please edit your question and provide this information, particularly showing what you've attempted. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done it with such way:

```
WITH Subordinates (Id, ParentId) AS (
    SELECT Id, Id as ParentId
    FROM Employees
    UNION ALL
    SELECT e.Id, s.ParentId
    FROM Employees e INNER JOIN Subordinates s ON (s.Id = e.ChiefId)
)

SELECT emain.Name,
        (CASE 
            WHEN (SELECT CAST((strftime('%Y', date('now', '-1 month')) + strftime('%j', date('now', '-1 month')) / 365.2422) - (strftime('%Y', emain.EnrollmentDate) + strftime('%j', emain.EnrollmentDate) / 365.2422) AS INT)) * (SELECT p.YearPercent FROM Position p WHERE p.Id = emain.PositionId) >= (SELECT p.MaxYearPercent FROM Position p WHERE p.Id = emain.PositionId)
            THEN emain.BaseSalary + emain.BaseSalary * (SELECT p.MaxYearPercent FROM Position p WHERE p.Id = emain.PositionId)
            ELSE emain.BaseSalary + emain.BaseSalary * (SELECT CAST((strftime('%Y', date('now', '-1 month')) + strftime('%j', date('now', '-1 month')) / 365.2422) - (strftime('%Y', emain.EnrollmentDate) + strftime('%j', emain.EnrollmentDate) / 365.2422) AS INT)) * (SELECT p.YearPercent FROM Position p WHERE p.Id = emain.PositionId)
        END) +
        (Case
            WHEN emain.PositionId = 1 
                THEN 0
            WHEN emain.PositionId = 2 
                THEN (
                    SELECT ifnull(SUM(
                        CASE
                            WHEN (SELECT CAST((strftime('%Y', date('now', '-1 month')) + strftime('%j', date('now', '-1 month')) / 365.2422) - (strftime('%Y', s.EnrollmentDate) + strftime('%j', s.EnrollmentDate) / 365.2422) AS INT)) * (SELECT p.YearPercent FROM Position p WHERE p.Id = s.PositionId) >= (SELECT p.MaxYearPercent FROM Position p WHERE p.Id = s.PositionId)
                            THEN s.BaseSalary + s.BaseSalary * (SELECT p.MaxYearPercent FROM Position p WHERE p.Id = s.PositionId)
                            ELSE s.BaseSalary + s.BaseSalary * (SELECT CAST((strftime('%Y', date('now', '-1 month')) + strftime('%j', date('now', '-1 month')) / 365.2422) - (strftime('%Y', s.EnrollmentDate) + strftime('%j', s.EnrollmentDate) / 365.2422) AS INT)) * (SELECT p.YearPercent FROM Position p WHERE p.Id = s.PositionId)
                        END),0)
                    FROM Employees e
                    LEFT JOIN Employees s ON e.Id = s.ChiefId AND e.Id = emain.Id
                ) * 0.005
            WHEN emain.PositionId = 3
                THEN (
                    SELECT ifnull(SUM(
                        CASE
                            WHEN (SELECT CAST((strftime('%Y', date('now', '-1 month')) + strftime('%j', date('now', '-1 month')) / 365.2422) - (strftime('%Y', e1.EnrollmentDate) + strftime('%j', e1.EnrollmentDate) / 365.2422) AS INT)) * (SELECT p.YearPercent FROM Position p WHERE p.Id = e1.PositionId) >= (SELECT p.MaxYearPercent FROM Position p WHERE p.Id = e1.PositionId)
                            THEN e1.BaseSalary + e1.BaseSalary * (SELECT p.MaxYearPercent FROM Position p WHERE p.Id = e1.PositionId)
                            ELSE e1.BaseSalary + e1.BaseSalary * (SELECT CAST((strftime('%Y', date('now', '-1 month')) + strftime('%j', date('now', '-1 month')) / 365.2422) - (strftime('%Y', e1.EnrollmentDate) + strftime('%j', e1.EnrollmentDate) / 365.2422) AS INT)) * (SELECT p.YearPercent FROM Position p WHERE p.Id = e1.PositionId)
                        END
                    ),0) as 'Pay'
                    FROM Subordinates s
                    JOIN Employees e ON e.Id = s.ParentId
                    LEFT JOIN Employees e1 ON e1.Id = s.Id AND s.Id != s.ParentId AND e.Id = emain.Id
                ) * 0.003
        END) AS 'Month 1',

        (CASE 
            WHEN (SELECT CAST((strftime('%Y', date('now', '-2 month')) + strftime('%j', date('now', '-2 month')) / 365.2422) - (strftime('%Y', emain.EnrollmentDate) + strftime('%j', emain.EnrollmentDate) / 365.2422) AS INT)) * (SELECT p.YearPercent FROM Position p WHERE p.Id = emain.PositionId) >= (SELECT p.MaxYearPercent FROM Position p WHERE p.Id = emain.PositionId)
            THEN emain.BaseSalary + emain.BaseSalary * (SELECT p.MaxYearPercent FROM Position p WHERE p.Id = emain.PositionId)
            ELSE emain.BaseSalary + emain.BaseSalary * (SELECT CAST((strftime('%Y', date('now', '-2 month')) + strftime('%j', date('now', '-2 month')) / 365.2422) - (strftime('%Y', emain.EnrollmentDate) + strftime('%j', emain.EnrollmentDate) / 365.2422) AS INT)) * (SELECT p.YearPercent FROM Position p WHERE p.Id = emain.PositionId)
        END) +
        (Case
            WHEN emain.PositionId = 1 
                THEN 0
            WHEN emain.PositionId = 2 
                THEN (
                    SELECT ifnull(SUM(
                        CASE
                            WHEN (SELECT CAST((strftime('%Y', date('now', '-2 month')) + strftime('%j', date('now', '-2 month')) / 365.2422) - (strftime('%Y', s.EnrollmentDate) + strftime('%j', s.EnrollmentDate) / 365.2422) AS INT)) * (SELECT p.YearPercent FROM Position p WHERE p.Id = s.PositionId) >= (SELECT p.MaxYearPercent FROM Position p WHERE p.Id = s.PositionId)
                            THEN s.BaseSalary + s.BaseSalary * (SELECT p.MaxYearPercent FROM Position p WHERE p.Id = s.PositionId)
                            ELSE s.BaseSalary + s.BaseSalary * (SELECT CAST((strftime('%Y', date('now', '-2 month')) + strftime('%j', date('now', '-2 month')) / 365.2422) - (strftime('%Y', s.EnrollmentDate) + strftime('%j', s.EnrollmentDate) / 365.2422) AS INT)) * (SELECT p.YearPercent FROM Position p WHERE p.Id = s.PositionId)
                        END),0)
                    FROM Employees e
                    LEFT JOIN Employees s ON e.Id = s.ChiefId AND e.Id = emain.Id
                ) * 0.005
            WHEN emain.PositionId = 3
                THEN (
                    SELECT ifnull(SUM(
                        CASE
                            WHEN (SELECT CAST((strftime('%Y', date('now', '-2 month')) + strftime('%j', date('now', '-2 month')) / 365.2422) - (strftime('%Y', e1.EnrollmentDate) + strftime('%j', e1.EnrollmentDate) / 365.2422) AS INT)) * (SELECT p.YearPercent FROM Position p WHERE p.Id = e1.PositionId) >= (SELECT p.MaxYearPercent FROM Position p WHERE p.Id = e1.PositionId)
                            THEN e1.BaseSalary + e1.BaseSalary * (SELECT p.MaxYearPercent FROM Position p WHERE p.Id = e1.PositionId)
                            ELSE e1.BaseSalary + e1.BaseSalary * (SELECT CAST((strftime('%Y', date('now', '-2 month')) + strftime('%j', date('now', '-2 month')) / 365.2422) - (strftime('%Y', e1.EnrollmentDate) + strftime('%j', e1.EnrollmentDate) / 365.2422) AS INT)) * (SELECT p.YearPercent FROM Position p WHERE p.Id = e1.PositionId)
                        END
                    ),0) as 'Pay'
                    FROM Subordinates s
                    JOIN Employees e ON e.Id = s.ParentId
                    LEFT JOIN Employees e1 ON e1.Id = s.Id AND s.Id != s.ParentId AND e.Id = emain.Id
                ) * 0.003
        END) AS 'Month 2',

        (CASE 
            WHEN (SELECT CAST((strftime('%Y', date('now', '-3 month')) + strftime('%j', date('now', '-3 month')) / 365.2422) - (strftime('%Y', emain.EnrollmentDate) + strftime('%j', emain.EnrollmentDate) / 365.2422) AS INT)) * (SELECT p.YearPercent FROM Position p WHERE p.Id = emain.PositionId) >= (SELECT p.MaxYearPercent FROM Position p WHERE p.Id = emain.PositionId)
            THEN emain.BaseSalary + emain.BaseSalary * (SELECT p.MaxYearPercent FROM Position p WHERE p.Id = emain.PositionId)
            ELSE emain.BaseSalary + emain.BaseSalary * (SELECT CAST((strftime('%Y', date('now', '-3 month')) + strftime('%j', date('now', '-3 month')) / 365.2422) - (strftime('%Y', emain.EnrollmentDate) + strftime('%j', emain.EnrollmentDate) / 365.2422) AS INT)) * (SELECT p.YearPercent FROM Position p WHERE p.Id = emain.PositionId)
        END) +
        (Case
            WHEN emain.PositionId = 1 
                THEN 0
            WHEN emain.PositionId = 2 
                THEN (
                    SELECT ifnull(SUM(
                        CASE
                            WHEN (SELECT CAST((strftime('%Y', date('now', '-3 month')) + strftime('%j', date('now', '-3 month')) / 365.2422) - (strftime('%Y', s.EnrollmentDate) + strftime('%j', s.EnrollmentDate) / 365.2422) AS INT)) * (SELECT p.YearPercent FROM Position p WHERE p.Id = s.PositionId) >= (SELECT p.MaxYearPercent FROM Position p WHERE p.Id = s.PositionId)
                            THEN s.BaseSalary + s.BaseSalary * (SELECT p.MaxYearPercent FROM Position p WHERE p.Id = s.PositionId)
                            ELSE s.BaseSalary + s.BaseSalary * (SELECT CAST((strftime('%Y', date('now', '-3 month')) + strftime('%j', date('now', '-3 month')) / 365.2422) - (strftime('%Y', s.EnrollmentDate) + strftime('%j', s.EnrollmentDate) / 365.2422) AS INT)) * (SELECT p.YearPercent FROM Position p WHERE p.Id = s.PositionId)
                        END),0)
                    FROM Employees e
                    LEFT JOIN Employees s ON e.Id = s.ChiefId AND e.Id = emain.Id
                ) * 0.005
            WHEN emain.PositionId = 3
                THEN (
                    SELECT ifnull(SUM(
                        CASE
                            WHEN (SELECT CAST((strftime('%Y', date('now', '-3 month')) + strftime('%j', date('now', '-3 month')) / 365.2422) - (strftime('%Y', e1.EnrollmentDate) + strftime('%j', e1.EnrollmentDate) / 365.2422) AS INT)) * (SELECT p.YearPercent FROM Position p WHERE p.Id = e1.PositionId) >= (SELECT p.MaxYearPercent FROM Position p WHERE p.Id = e1.PositionId)
                            THEN e1.BaseSalary + e1.BaseSalary * (SELECT p.MaxYearPercent FROM Position p WHERE p.Id = e1.PositionId)
                            ELSE e1.BaseSalary + e1.BaseSalary * (SELECT CAST((strftime('%Y', date('now', '-3 month')) + strftime('%j', date('now', '-3 month')) / 365.2422) - (strftime('%Y', e1.EnrollmentDate) + strftime('%j', e1.EnrollmentDate) / 365.2422) AS INT)) * (SELECT p.YearPercent FROM Position p WHERE p.Id = e1.PositionId)
                        END
                    ),0) as 'Pay'
                    FROM Subordinates s
                    JOIN Employees e ON e.Id = s.ParentId
                    LEFT JOIN Employees e1 ON e1.Id = s.Id AND s.Id != s.ParentId AND e.Id = emain.Id
                ) * 0.003
        END) AS 'Month 3',

        (CASE 
            WHEN (SELECT CAST((strftime('%Y', date('now', '-4 month')) + strftime('%j', date('now', '-4 month')) / 365.2422) - (strftime('%Y', emain.EnrollmentDate) + strftime('%j', emain.EnrollmentDate) / 365.2422) AS INT)) * (SELECT p.YearPercent FROM Position p WHERE p.Id = emain.PositionId) >= (SELECT p.MaxYearPercent FROM Position p WHERE p.Id = emain.PositionId)
            THEN emain.BaseSalary + emain.BaseSalary * (SELECT p.MaxYearPercent FROM Position p WHERE p.Id = emain.PositionId)
            ELSE emain.BaseSalary + emain.BaseSalary * (SELECT CAST((strftime('%Y', date('now', '-4 month')) + strftime('%j', date('now', '-4 month')) / 365.2422) - (strftime('%Y', emain.EnrollmentDate) + strftime('%j', emain.EnrollmentDate) / 365.2422) AS INT)) * (SELECT p.YearPercent FROM Position p WHERE p.Id = emain.PositionId)
        END) +
        (Case
            WHEN emain.PositionId = 1 
                THEN 0
            WHEN emain.PositionId = 2 
                THEN (
                    SELECT ifnull(SUM(
                        CASE
                            WHEN (SELECT CAST((strftime('%Y', date('now', '-4 month')) + strftime('%j', date('now', '-4 month')) / 365.2422) - (strftime('%Y', s.EnrollmentDate) + strftime('%j', s.EnrollmentDate) / 365.2422) AS INT)) * (SELECT p.YearPercent FROM Position p WHERE p.Id = s.PositionId) >= (SELECT p.MaxYearPercent FROM Position p WHERE p.Id = s.PositionId)
                            THEN s.BaseSalary + s.BaseSalary * (SELECT p.MaxYearPercent FROM Position p WHERE p.Id = s.PositionId)
                            ELSE s.BaseSalary + s.BaseSalary * (SELECT CAST((strftime('%Y', date('now', '-4 month')) + strftime('%j', date('now', '-4 month')) / 365.2422) - (strftime('%Y', s.EnrollmentDate) + strftime('%j', s.EnrollmentDate) / 365.2422) AS INT)) * (SELECT p.YearPercent FROM Position p WHERE p.Id = s.PositionId)
                        END),0)
                    FROM Employees e
                    LEFT JOIN Employees s ON e.Id = s.ChiefId AND e.Id = emain.Id
                ) * 0.005
            WHEN emain.PositionId = 3
                THEN (
                    SELECT ifnull(SUM(
                        CASE
                            WHEN (SELECT CAST((strftime('%Y', date('now', '-4 month')) + strftime('%j', date('now', '-4 month')) / 365.2422) - (strftime('%Y', e1.EnrollmentDate) + strftime('%j', e1.EnrollmentDate) / 365.2422) AS INT)) * (SELECT p.YearPercent FROM Position p WHERE p.Id = e1.PositionId) >= (SELECT p.MaxYearPercent FROM Position p WHERE p.Id = e1.PositionId)
                            THEN e1.BaseSalary + e1.BaseSalary * (SELECT p.MaxYearPercent FROM Position p WHERE p.Id = e1.PositionId)
                            ELSE e1.BaseSalary + e1.BaseSalary * (SELECT CAST((strftime('%Y', date('now', '-4 month')) + strftime('%j', date('now', '-4 month')) / 365.2422) - (strftime('%Y', e1.EnrollmentDate) + strftime('%j', e1.EnrollmentDate) / 365.2422) AS INT)) * (SELECT p.YearPercent FROM Position p WHERE p.Id = e1.PositionId)
                        END
                    ),0) as 'Pay'
                    FROM Subordinates s
                    JOIN Employees e ON e.Id = s.ParentId
                    LEFT JOIN Employees e1 ON e1.Id = s.Id AND s.Id != s.ParentId AND e.Id = emain.Id
                ) * 0.003
        END) AS 'Month 4',

        (CASE 
            WHEN (SELECT CAST((strftime('%Y', date('now', '-5 month')) + strftime('%j', date('now', '-5 month')) / 365.2422) - (strftime('%Y', emain.EnrollmentDate) + strftime('%j', emain.EnrollmentDate) / 365.2422) AS INT)) * (SELECT p.YearPercent FROM Position p WHERE p.Id = emain.PositionId) >= (SELECT p.MaxYearPercent FROM Position p WHERE p.Id = emain.PositionId)
            THEN emain.BaseSalary + emain.BaseSalary * (SELECT p.MaxYearPercent FROM Position p WHERE p.Id = emain.PositionId)
            ELSE emain.BaseSalary + emain.BaseSalary * (SELECT CAST((strftime('%Y', date('now', '-5 month')) + strftime('%j', date('now', '-5 month')) / 365.2422) - (strftime('%Y', emain.EnrollmentDate) + strftime('%j', emain.EnrollmentDate) / 365.2422) AS INT)) * (SELECT p.YearPercent FROM Position p WHERE p.Id = emain.PositionId)
        END) +
        (Case
            WHEN emain.PositionId = 1 
                THEN 0
            WHEN emain.PositionId = 2 
                THEN (
                    SELECT ifnull(SUM(
                        CASE
                            WHEN (SELECT CAST((strftime('%Y', date('now', '-5 month')) + strftime('%j', date('now', '-5 month')) / 365.2422) - (strftime('%Y', s.EnrollmentDate) + strftime('%j', s.EnrollmentDate) / 365.2422) AS INT)) * (SELECT p.YearPercent FROM Position p WHERE p.Id = s.PositionId) >= (SELECT p.MaxYearPercent FROM Position p WHERE p.Id = s.PositionId)
                            THEN s.BaseSalary + s.BaseSalary * (SELECT p.MaxYearPercent FROM Position p WHERE p.Id = s.PositionId)
                            ELSE s.BaseSalary + s.BaseSalary * (SELECT CAST((strftime('%Y', date('now', '-5 month')) + strftime('%j', date('now', '-5 month')) / 365.2422) - (strftime('%Y', s.EnrollmentDate) + strftime('%j', s.EnrollmentDate) / 365.2422) AS INT)) * (SELECT p.YearPercent FROM Position p WHERE p.Id = s.PositionId)
                        END),0)
                    FROM Employees e
                    LEFT JOIN Employees s ON e.Id = s.ChiefId AND e.Id = emain.Id
                ) * 0.005
            WHEN emain.PositionId = 3
                THEN (
                    SELECT ifnull(SUM(
                        CASE
                            WHEN (SELECT CAST((strftime('%Y', date('now', '-5 month')) + strftime('%j', date('now', '-5 month')) / 365.2422) - (strftime('%Y', e1.EnrollmentDate) + strftime('%j', e1.EnrollmentDate) / 365.2422) AS INT)) * (SELECT p.YearPercent FROM Position p WHERE p.Id = e1.PositionId) >= (SELECT p.MaxYearPercent FROM Position p WHERE p.Id = e1.PositionId)
                            THEN e1.BaseSalary + e1.BaseSalary * (SELECT p.MaxYearPercent FROM Position p WHERE p.Id = e1.PositionId)
                            ELSE e1.BaseSalary + e1.BaseSalary * (SELECT CAST((strftime('%Y', date('now', '-5 month')) + strftime('%j', date('now', '-5 month')) / 365.2422) - (strftime('%Y', e1.EnrollmentDate) + strftime('%j', e1.EnrollmentDate) / 365.2422) AS INT)) * (SELECT p.YearPercent FROM Position p WHERE p.Id = e1.PositionId)
                        END
                    ),0) as 'Pay'
                    FROM Subordinates s
                    JOIN Employees e ON e.Id = s.ParentId
                    LEFT JOIN Employees e1 ON e1.Id = s.Id AND s.Id != s.ParentId AND e.Id = emain.Id
                ) * 0.003
        END) AS 'Month 5',

        (CASE 
            WHEN (SELECT CAST((strftime('%Y', date('now', '-6 month')) + strftime('%j', date('now', '-6 month')) / 365.2422) - (strftime('%Y', emain.EnrollmentDate) + strftime('%j', emain.EnrollmentDate) / 365.2422) AS INT)) * (SELECT p.YearPercent FROM Position p WHERE p.Id = emain.PositionId) >= (SELECT p.MaxYearPercent FROM Position p WHERE p.Id = emain.PositionId)
            THEN emain.BaseSalary + emain.BaseSalary * (SELECT p.MaxYearPercent FROM Position p WHERE p.Id = emain.PositionId)
            ELSE emain.BaseSalary + emain.BaseSalary * (SELECT CAST((strftime('%Y', date('now', '-6 month')) + strftime('%j', date('now', '-6 month')) / 365.2422) - (strftime('%Y', emain.EnrollmentDate) + strftime('%j', emain.EnrollmentDate) / 365.2422) AS INT)) * (SELECT p.YearPercent FROM Position p WHERE p.Id = emain.PositionId)
        END) +
        (Case
            WHEN emain.PositionId = 1 
                THEN 0
            WHEN emain.PositionId = 2 
                THEN (
                    SELECT ifnull(SUM(
                        CASE
                            WHEN (SELECT CAST((strftime('%Y', date('now', '-6 month')) + strftime('%j', date('now', '-6 month')) / 365.2422) - (strftime('%Y', s.EnrollmentDate) + strftime('%j', s.EnrollmentDate) / 365.2422) AS INT)) * (SELECT p.YearPercent FROM Position p WHERE p.Id = s.PositionId) >= (SELECT p.MaxYearPercent FROM Position p WHERE p.Id = s.PositionId)
                            THEN s.BaseSalary + s.BaseSalary * (SELECT p.MaxYearPercent FROM Position p WHERE p.Id = s.PositionId)
                            ELSE s.BaseSalary + s.BaseSalary * (SELECT CAST((strftime('%Y', date('now', '-6 month')) + strftime('%j', date('now', '-6 month')) / 365.2422) - (strftime('%Y', s.EnrollmentDate) + strftime('%j', s.EnrollmentDate) / 365.2422) AS INT)) * (SELECT p.YearPercent FROM Position p WHERE p.Id = s.PositionId)
                        END),0)
                    FROM Employees e
                    LEFT JOIN Employees s ON e.Id = s.ChiefId AND e.Id = emain.Id
                ) * 0.005
            WHEN emain.PositionId = 3
                THEN (
                    SELECT ifnull(SUM(
                        CASE
                            WHEN (SELECT CAST((strftime('%Y', date('now', '-6 month')) + strftime('%j', date('now', '-6 month')) / 365.2422) - (strftime('%Y', e1.EnrollmentDate) + strftime('%j', e1.EnrollmentDate) / 365.2422) AS INT)) * (SELECT p.YearPercent FROM Position p WHERE p.Id = e1.PositionId) >= (SELECT p.MaxYearPercent FROM Position p WHERE p.Id = e1.PositionId)
                            THEN e1.BaseSalary + e1.BaseSalary * (SELECT p.MaxYearPercent FROM Position p WHERE p.Id = e1.PositionId)
                            ELSE e1.BaseSalary + e1.BaseSalary * (SELECT CAST((strftime('%Y', date('now', '-6 month')) + strftime('%j', date('now', '-6 month')) / 365.2422) - (strftime('%Y', e1.EnrollmentDate) + strftime('%j', e1.EnrollmentDate) / 365.2422) AS INT)) * (SELECT p.YearPercent FROM Position p WHERE p.Id = e1.PositionId)
                        END
                    ),0) as 'Pay'
                    FROM Subordinates s
                    JOIN Employees e ON e.Id = s.ParentId
                    LEFT JOIN Employees e1 ON e1.Id = s.Id AND s.Id != s.ParentId AND e.Id = emain.Id
                ) * 0.003
        END) AS 'Month 6'
FROM Employees emain;
```